# Struts 1.3.8 is compatible with jdk 1.6?

Tags: struts, java, struts-1

I have searched the net to see if struts 1.3.8 is compatible with jdk 1.6.
If anyone does know, just replay

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STR-3199

Comment: Ah, making my response a great example of circular reasoning. I didn't pick up on that seeing as how the reporter wasn't named "Hobbit Programmer."

Comment: @Anca Z: that would have been a good information to add to your initial question. Seening as it isn't too full of information yet.

Comment: i'm going to comment on that question to say that someone on StackOverflow says they're not compatible. That should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Struts 1.2 with jdk1.6 and i believe even Struts 1.3.8 should be compatible with jdk 1.6.